# Image not upload perfectly in ftp

Tags: image

Hi I'm trying to upload my image in ftp, but the image is not upload perfectly.
Please Help
this is the image
http://klineconstruction.com.au/images/designandconstruct-header.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you on doing transfers in Binary mode? (just write "binary" on the connection)

Also, check out [this site](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/ftp.html) with the list of basic commands for FTP.

Comment: Binary mode? I have no idea, I don't how to know.

Comment: go to the menu Transfer > Transfer Type > Binary

Comment: I change to transfers to binary mode, but still got same result

Comment: Can you clarify what's the diferences you see on the image?

Comment: the white area of the image is been cut, that will be full image.